# Django/Python Multiple records

Tags: python, django

I have a program that compares values from the database and from a CSV file. My program works like this.

1. Database has values.
2. User uploads a file (multiple users multiple
   files).
3. The program compares the values from the database and the
   CSV files and gives an output.

Which tells me that this particular value was found in this user's file.
But I want the program to show me that if the value was found in the other user's file or not.
Here is a working example.

- DB Values = `[1,23,33,445,6656,88]`

Example values of the CSV files:

- File 1 values = `[1,23,445,77,66,556,54]`
- File 2 values = `[1,23,45,77,366]`
- File 3 values = `[1,23,5,77,5356,524]`

Output needed:

```py
{'1':[(user1, some value),(user2, some value)...]}
```

Here my code:

```py
def LCR(request):
    template = "LCR\LCRGen.html"
    dest = Destination.objects.values_list('dest_num', flat=True)
    ratelist   =  { }
    csv_file   =  { }
    data_set   =  { }
    io_string  =  { }
    vendor = RateFile.objects.values_list()
    v_count = vendor.count()
    for v_id, v_name, v_file in vendor:
        vendor_name = str(v_name)
        vendornames = str(v_name)
        vendornames = { }
        for desNum in dest:
            desNum = str(desNum)
            for countvar in range(v_count):
                csv_file[vendor_name] = RateFile.objects.get(id=v_id).ven_file
                data_set[vendor_name] = csv_file[vendor_name].read().decode("UTF-8")
                io_string[vendor_name] = io.StringIO(data_set[vendor_name])
                next(io_string[vendor_name])
                for column in csv.reader(io_string[vendor_name], delimiter=str(u",")):
                    vendornames[column[0]] = column[1]
                    for venNum, venValue in vendornames.items():
                            venlen = len(venNum)
                            deslen = len(desNum)
                            if venlen >= deslen or venlen <= deslen:
                                if desNum[:-1] == venNum[:-1] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-2] and desNum[:-3] == venNum[:-3]:
                                    ratelist[desNum] = [(vendor_name, venValue),]
                                    if (vendor_name, venValue) in ratelist[desNum]:
                                        ratelist[desNum] = [
                                            (vendor_name, venValue),]
                                elif desNum[:-1] == venNum[:-2] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-3] and desNum[:-3] == venNum[:-4]:
                                    ratelist[desNum] = [(vendor_name, venValue),]
                                    if (vendor_name, venValue) in ratelist[desNum]:
                                        ratelist[desNum] = [
                                            (vendor_name, venValue),]
                                elif desNum[:-1] == desNum[:-3] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-4] and desNum[:-3] == venNum[:-5]:
                                    ratelist[desNum] = [(vendor_name, venValue),]
                                elif desNum[:-1] == venNum[:-5] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-6]:
                                    ratelist[desNum] = [(vendor_name, venValue),]
                                    if (vendor_name, venValue) in ratelist[desNum]:
                                        ratelist[desNum] = [
                                            (vendor_name, venValue),]
                                else:
                                    pass
    print ( ratelist )
    return render ( request, template, { "ratelist" : ratelist } )
```

#### Output

`Zong`, `Tata` are usernames and the float values is their respective value for the key value of the dictionary.

```py
{'12': [('Zong', ' 0.026')], '213': [('Tata', ' 4.150')], '49': [('Tata', ' 0.531')], '30': [('Zong', ' 0.87')], '454': [('Tata', ' 0.531')], '374': [('Zong', ' 0.87')],
```

Comment: can you also provide your actual code output, errors etc

Comment: Please check updated ver

Comment: it is not clear, where `0.026` comes out? The values in your files you said are: `[1,23,445,77,66,556,54]`

Comment: They are example values. Each user has a price to offer for each value they offer. thus multiple users have a different offer for one or many numbers.

Comment: user 1 offers .34 for '1' and user 2 offers 1.22 for '1'. That the other number next to the user name.

Comment: You and I have number 1 in our file. I want the program to show your name as well as mine in the users that offer the number. Hopefully you understand it now

Comment: does the `file1` represents all offers of `username1` or all first offers of all users?

Comment: file1 is for user 1 . file2 for user 2

Answer (score 0):

This is what you asked for:

```py
### your data example
db = [1,23,33,445,66,556,88]
us1 = [1,23,445,77,66,556,54]
us2 = [1,23,45,77,366]
### create a list of usernames (to use the string name in dictionary)
userlist = [ "us1", "us2" ]

### intialize the dict for results
values_dict = {}
### open the loop on DB values
for value in db :
    # open loop on userlist
    for user in userlist :
        # if value is found in user list of values
        if value in eval(user) :
            # if values still NOT a key of results dictionary create the key with the tuple list as values
            if value not in values_dict :
                values_dict.update({ value : [ ( user, value ) ] })
            # else just append the tuple (username, value) to the results dictionary for the DB value corresponding key
            else :
                values_dict[value].append([ ( user, value ) ])


values_dict

### OUTPUT: 
{1: [('us1', 1), [('us2', 1)]], 23: [('us1', 23), [('us2', 23)]], 445: [('us1', 445)], 66: [('us1', 66)], 556: [('us1', 556)]}
```

but it makes no sense cause it simply check if a value is in the user list of values and add a tuple just to confirm it, it doesn't require all this code, could be simplified a lot. But I'm thinking that I misunderstood your question (please review the english), probably you need to use the DB value as the key to retrieve another value from the user...please review and update